# Should I use a Docker container as a GitLab Runner?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, gitlab-ci-runner

Newbie to GitLab CI/CD here.

I'd like to use a linux base container as the Runner. Reason being I only have access to a Windows VM, and I'd rather not have to write PowerShell scripts build/test/deploy. Also, the build is using Spring Boot + maven, and I'm doubtful that the build scripts provided by Spring will run on Windows.

To further the problem, the build done by maven+spring spins up a container to execute the build. In other words, my build would run a container in a container, which seems feasible based on this [blog](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/).

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Edit based on @JoSSte 's feedback:

Are there any better approaches to setup a runner besides needing a container inside a container? For instance, if WSL enables running bash scripts, can the Windows VM act as the build server?

And to satisfy @JoSSte's request to make this question less opinion based, are there any best practices to approach a problem like this?

Comment: I think your question is opinion based, and therefore either needs reformulation  or specification. consider kubernetes or vagrant or docker. [ask]

Comment: What do you mean by the mvn build spins up a container?

Comment: @lane.maxwell The build scripts provided by Spring Boot use a spring boot plugin for maven. So when you run `mvnw spring-boot:build-image` to build an image containing the jar, spring boot launches a [Paketo Build Pack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks), which is Docker container, and does the build inside it.

Comment: Ah, you're using the spring-boot plugin to build your container.  There's nothing wrong with running that inside of another container.  I tend to just define a Dockerfile and run `docker build .` as one of my build steps.  This also requires the docker daemon to be running in the build container, so it's half a dozen of one, six of the other.